# Smoothen data fast and endless

Tags: c++, smoothing

I have to read measured values (floats) and display them as a trace in real time. The data is noisy and I need to smoothen the trace. My current solution is using a ring buffer. In and endless loop I write the new value in the buffer and I display the average of the buffer. I can do this efficiently by keeping the buffer sum.

```
class cRingAveragerF {
public:
    cRingAveragerF(uint size, float initval) {
        m_Sum = 0;
        m_Pointer = 0;
        m_Size = size;
        m_pBuffer = new float[size];
        for (uint i = 0; i < m_Size; i++) m_pBuffer[i] = initval;
        m_Sum = m_Size*initval;
    }

    ~cRingAveragerF() { delete[]m_pBuffer;}

    float getAv() { return m_Sum / (float)m_Size; }

    void push(float val) {
        m_Sum -= m_pBuffer[m_Pointer];
        m_Sum += val;
        m_pBuffer[m_Pointer] = val;
        m_Pointer++;
        if (m_Size == m_Pointer)m_Pointer = 0;
    }

private:
    uint m_Size;
    float* m_pBuffer;
    uint m_Pointer;
    float m_Sum;
};
```

My questions are:

- can I increase efficiency e.g. by using any in-build funcions (I use Windows VS2015 and OpenCV)?
- Are there better solutions for smoothening than averaging with somewhat equal efficiency?

Comment: The biggest question is: if it works, why change it? Micro optimizations are rarely worth it and if there's no performance issue they're a waste of time.

Comment: Secondly, unrelated and offtopic: why are you using VS 2015? It's 5 years old and has been succeeded by two new versions already...

Comment: @JHBonarius: First, my solution might work but creates a delay the bigger the buffer is, second, in a proffessional environment you cannot change your setup every day. Also, the c++ standard does not change over night.

Comment: ?!?!?!?!? "in a proffessional environment you cannot change your setup every day" Agreed (although in my company we all keep VS up to date), but we're not talking about days, but *5 years*. An talking about the C++ standard: I'm not sure about the C++14 support of VS2015, but in the mean time we've had C++17 and C++20 now, so yes: the C++ standard *has* changed. Again: not over night, but in **5** years.

Comment: About the increase in delay. Why do you think so? Did you measure it? Always measure.